# Getting value from a parent row to child row, with a recursive MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I want to have a value from a parent row to be in the child row, the problem is that everything has a multiple number of levels. Its easier if I show you.

Here is what I have:
[image]

I want to have something like:

```
id | question_id | text
74 | 47          | Test answer
75 | 47          | Another answer
76 | 47          | Sub answer
77 | 47          | Sub sub answer
```

I want to get a list of all first level parents for each answer(row). The top level parent of id 77 is 75, and 75 has a question_id of 47, and that is exactly what I need. Because this way I am able to count() total answers from question_id 47.

I investigated a bit, an tried the following code:

```
SELECT @pv:=id AS id, answered_at, parent 
FROM qa_answers
JOIN (SELECT @pv:=75) AS tmp
WHERE parent = @pv
```

But this returns only for id 75, I want to show me everything. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'm not a SQL expert.

Comment: Use recursive CTEs in MySQL 8+.

Comment: any link to help me understand what it is ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will helps you.

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products_t` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `products_t` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`, `sub_id`) VALUES
(74, 'category15', '47', NULL),
(75, 'category16', '47', NULL),
(76, 'category19', NULL, '75'),
(77, 'category20', NULL, '76'),
(80, 'category80', NULL, '50'),
(81, 'category81', '50', NULL);
```

Query

```
select  id,
        name,
        IFNULL(parent_id,'47' ) as parent_id
from    (select * from products_t
         order by parent_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '47') initialisation
where   (find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) or find_in_set(sub_id, @pv) )
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

Here, the value specified in @pv := '47' should be set to the id of the parent you want to select all the descendants of.

Result

```
id  name        parent_id 
74  category15  47
75  category16  47
76  category19  47
77  category20  47
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't do what I asked. But I think I understand your logic, maybe I can tweak and make it work

Comment: @rafamds thanks for you comment, Please check the edited answer.

Comment: "Try this"-answers are always dangerous as they very rarely contain some explanation. This makes it impossible for the OP and other readers to learn from it, so please edit your answer and add some explanation to it